# Android Flipboard animation between two Activities

Tags: android, animation

How to animate a Flipboard animation between two activities?

I need the Animation to look like [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1fTI7oYfbI).

Comment: see here http://openaphid.github.com/blog/2012/05/21/how-to-implement-flipboard-animation-on-android/

Comment: @RachelGallen This one is not between two activities, only between two Layouts..

Comment: is this more like it http://oreilly.com/pub/a/javascript/archive/flashhacks.html?page=1

Comment: @RachelGallen I don't need the Curl animation, I need to look exactly like on the video or like the real Flipboard application :/

Comment: @RachelGallen I've managed to create the exact animation from the first link you gave me, but the thing is that I can't manipulate with those layouts after adding them in the contentView, they are useless, can't click on the buttons, they are like pictures :/

Comment: check this out on github https://github.com/openaphid/android-flip/tree/master/FlipView